# Moving a player towards the mouse direction?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs, pointerlock

I'm looking for a simple line of code or an API, if it is as simple as that.

I am using BabylonJS to make an online game, and I have run into a problem. I can't find anything on the documentation to support my problem. I am using

```
canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock || canvas.mozRequestPointerLock;
    canvas.requestPointerLock();
```

To lock the mouse, when normally you have to click and drag. I am also using this movement script for basic movement:

```
function KEY_DOWN(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 87)
    {
        player.position.z -= 0.5;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        player.position.x += 0.5;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 83)
    {
        player.position.z += 0.5;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 68)
    {
        player.position.x -= 0.5;
    }
}
```

This only transforms on an axis unfortunately. Is there any way to determine where my mouse is looking and move towards that point, and not just move on a fixed axis? I can't seem to find anything that has the exact methods I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any API, but it shouldn't be so bad, if I understand your problem correctly.  You'll need to hook into the mousemove event after the point has been locked, and instead of the simple handling like shown here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/ you would need to do your vector calculations against each vector of movement possible with the keys in that handler.  Effectively, you would compute the x, y, z deltas that each key press corresponds to within your pointerlockchange handler based on the mouse deltas.  Probably not as bad as it sounds, since your mouse deltas are only going to affect up to 2 axes at a time.

Comment: To further illustrate what I mean, I have put together an example here that I think will help.  Unfortunately I couldn't use jsfiddle because its iframes block pointer locks.  My example is here, it translates pointer locked x/y mouse movement into normalized vectors that could be mapped to the arrow keys.  Depending on what your scenario is, you may need to flip things around, change the axes of rotation, etc. http://www.digitaldownpour.com/pointerlock/PointerLockTest.html

Comment: Basically the idea is that you need to decide around which 2 axes the locked pointer movements rotate (my example assumes that X mouse movement rotates about the Y axis, and Y mouse movement rotates about the X axis, which would be pretty typical).  Next you need to decide what movement the arrow keys constitute, in mine up translates to "forward", and so on (again, pretty typical).  Once those decisions are made, it's just the usual trigonometry to get a direction and magnitude for each of the four "directions".

Comment: I found some javascript I had kicking around for a rotating starfield, from at least 10 years ago.  I pulled in some of that code to create a variation on the example above, that specifically shows one approach for accomplishing what you ask for.  In the example, you "look" up/down, left/right using pointerlock mechanism, and can move using the arrow keys.  It's clunky, you can only move in one direction at a time, and rotation seems a little buggy, but it works well enough to show the idea: http://www.digitaldownpour.com/pointerlock/PointerLockStarfield.html

Comment: Took your advice, and got it to work out. Thank you!